# How to convert video file to multiform data in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I had tried this code but I can't get the path of the video and convert the file to multiform data is there is any other method to convert the file.The code works fine for image upload but for video I don't know what went wrong

```
    var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sample", ofType: "mp4")
                var data1 = NSData(contentsOfFile:path!)
                var videodata:NSData=NSData(data:data1!)
                var len = videodata.length
                println()
                var postlength:NSString = NSString(format:"%d",len)
                var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:"(liveurl)/mobile/post/video_post")!)


            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"


            var boundary = NSString(format:"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449")
            request.setValue(postlength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
            var contentType = NSString(format:"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary)

            request.addValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

            var postData = NSMutableData.alloc()
            println(request)
            postData.appendData(NSString(format:"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

            postData.appendData(NSString(format:"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"video.mp4\"\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
            postData.appendData(NSString(format:"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

            postData.appendData(videodata)
            println(videodata)
            postData.appendData(NSString(format:"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)


            println("postData")
            println(postData)
            request.HTTPBody = postData

            println("request")
            println(request)

            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData?, error: NSError!) -> Void in

                if (data != nil) {
                    println(response)
                    if let jsonArray: NSArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves, error: nil) as NSArray? {

                        let jsonObject: NSDictionary? = jsonArray.objectAtIndex(0) as? NSDictionary
                        println(jsonObject!)
                        if (jsonObject != nil) {
                            println("object: %@", jsonObject!)

                            if (jsonObject != nil) {
                                println("\(jsonObject)")
                                // process jsonResult
                            } else {
                                println("no response \(error)")
                                // couldn't load JSON, look at error
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Any errors? Compile errors, runtime, server-side errors?

Comment: This is the response I am getting from the server side((
        {
        status = "The file was only partially uploaded.";
    }
))

Comment: Whether I am encrypting the file Wrongly

Answer (score 0):

```
var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sample", ofType: "mp4")
          var data1 = NSData()
         var videodata: NSData? = NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile(path!) as? NSData
         var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:"the request url")!)

        var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"


   //the encoding begins     
        var boundary = NSString(format: "---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449")
        var contentType = NSString(format: "multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary)
         request.addValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        var body = NSMutableData.alloc()
         // Title

        body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData(NSString(format:"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\"\r\n\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData("Hello World".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!)


        body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fileToUpload\"; filename=\"sample.mp4\"\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData(NSString(format: "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData(videodata!)
        body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        request.HTTPBody = body

        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData?, error: NSError!) -> Void in

            if (data != nil) {
                if let jsonArray: NSArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSArray? {
                    println("json array\(jsonArray)")
                }
                else
                {
                 }
            }
        }
        }
```

Comment: This is not encrypting.