# File upload from swift to django

Tags: python, django, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload photos and videos from swift iOS app to amazon s3 using django backend. I found a django app to connect django to s3 using https://github.com/bradleyg/django-s3direct Problem is I have no idea how to upload a file from swift to django.

The django-s3direct I got working in the admin panel and they provide a nice method to generate a form for uploading the files but I don't know how to upload the files from swift using this plugin for django.

Should I find a different way of connecting the django backend to amazon s3? Is there a tutorial out there somewhere for this? (I can't find any)

Comment: First of all you need to connect swift filesystem somehow, is your media root on swift? I need more of a layout to help you. Also if youre on a vpn with swift / django server then it can be easy, that or serve the media using nginx and SMB depends on many factors

Comment: not sure what media root is... its on the iPhone.. I would like to connect using NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest... I found this on sending up multipart form data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045228/how-to-convert-video-file-to-multiform-data-in-swift but still no idea how to write the backend code for this

Comment: Well do you have django-rest-framework in use? you still need a way for the app to connect / authenticate with Django

Comment: Simplest way to get this done is build rest apis in django, give clients ability to log in with authtokens or whatever, from there the endpoint for post in s3direct should handle the rest.

Comment: yeh so I have rest framework in place. I just don't know how to handle the post data I send up in a request in order to upload to s3 using this plugin for django

Answer (score 1):

Your view should be able to receive `FILES` with the `POST` request and the regular thing to do when you receive an uploaded picture from regular html form. then all you have to do is to create **multipart** form in iOS and post it to the receiver url. Once you submit the photo in the form, you django application should do the S3 thing. So simply your question is how to post a selected image from iOS to a web-service form as a multipart form. This code demonstrate that.

```
var imageData :NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imagenReduced, 1.0);       
var request: NSMutableURLRequest?
let HTTPMethod: String = "POST"
var timeoutInterval: NSTimeInterval = 60
var HTTPShouldHandleCookies: Bool = false

request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request!.HTTPMethod = HTTPMethod
request!.timeoutInterval = timeoutInterval
request!.HTTPShouldHandleCookies = HTTPShouldHandleCookies


let boundary = "----------SwIfTeRhTtPrEqUeStBoUnDaRy"
let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)"
request!.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")
var body = NSMutableData();


 let tempData = NSMutableData()
 let fileName = filenames + ".jpg" //"prueba.jpg"
 let parameterName = "userfile"


let mimeType = "application/octet-stream"

tempData.appendData("--\(boundary)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
let fileNameContentDisposition = fileName != nil ? "filename=\"\(fileName)\"" : ""
let contentDisposition = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(parameterName)\"; \(fileNameContentDisposition)\r\n"
tempData.appendData(contentDisposition.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
tempData.appendData("Content-Type: \(mimeType)\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
tempData.appendData(imageData)
tempData.appendData("\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

body.appendData(tempData)

body.appendData("\r\n--\(boundary)--\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

request!.setValue("\(body.length)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
request!.HTTPBody = body



var vl_error :NSErrorPointer = nil
var responseData  = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request,returningResponse: nil, error:vl_error)

var results = NSString(data:responseData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
println("finish \(results)")
```

Comment: On Django side: request.FILES['what key is here"]?